# "Others" Appearing in CartoDB Legend

Tags: carto, legend

I've imported a SHP via zip folder, and it appears to import correctly in the Data View.

However, in Map View, when I select the Category option one of my twelve items is listed as "Others." In addition, when I change the visualized column, a different item is listed as "Others."

Does anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing incorrectly? Does my question make sense?
I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I had imported an earlier version, but deleted it. Does it have to do with importing an updated file?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Adding a screen capture of what you're asking about would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

CartoDB creates category maps based on the ten most numerous items in a column. If the number of unique items is above ten, the 11th, 12th, etc. are binned into "Other".

If you would like to change this, you can go to the [CartoCSS](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor/maps/#cartocss) tray and add additional rules to let your items show through.

Each additional rule looks like:

```
#layer[interesting_category_column="other_interesting_item"] {
    polygon-fill: new color in hex or rgb() function
}
```

You need to change the layer name to what the others are in your dataset, the column name to be what the others are like, and `other_interesting_item` to be the other item that you want to be symbolized. Further, you need to select a color for the scheme. The category items were chosen from [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) so you can select more colors that fit within that scheme.

To update your Legend, click on the [Legend tray](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor/maps/#legends) and then the blue `</>` in the upper right corner to update the HTML behind the legend to make your new item appear. There you simply copy the `<li> ... </li>` and update the hex color and words.